# How do i open more then one json file in a command

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to run this code that will send the links which will be opened from a json file, so i don't have to manually put in.

```
@commands.command()
async def socials(self, ctx):
    with open('twit.json', 'insta.json', 'yt.json', "r") as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())
        guildID = str(ctx.guild.id)
        insta = data[guildID]
        twit = data[guildID]
        yt = data[guildID]

    embed = discord.Embed(title = ctx.guild_name +' Socials', color = discord.Colour.blue())

    embed.add_field(name = 'Youtube', value = f'Subscribe to Our Youtube! \n{yt} ', inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = 'Instagram', value = f'Follow Our Instagram! \n{insta}', inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = 'Twitter', value = f'Follow Our Twitter! \n{twit}', inline  = False)

    embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url)
    embed.set_footer(icon_url=ctx.guild.icon_url)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

This is my error message.     Sorry if the problem is simple, I'm new to python.

```
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/DIscord Team Bot Tem/cogs/socials.py", line 195, in socials
with open('twit.json', 'insta.json', 'yt.json', "r") as f:
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

And this is the full error message

```
Ignoring exception in command socials:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/DIscord Team Bot Tem/cogs/socials.py", line 195, in socials
    with open('twit.json', 'insta.json', 'yt.json', "r") as f:
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 859, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `open()` function only opens one file; to open multiple files, you have to call it multiple times, either writing it out several times or in a loop.

For example, with a loop:

```
guildID = str(ctx.guild.id)
data = {}
for social in ('twit', 'insta', 'yt'):
    with open('%s.json' % social, 'r') as f:
        data[social] = json.load(f)[guildID]
```

Or, one after the other:

```
guildID = str(ctx.guild.id)
with open('twit.json', 'r') as f:
    twit = json.load(f)[guildID]
with open('insta.json', 'r') as f:
    insta = json.load(f)[guildID]
with open('yt.json', 'r') as f:
    yt = json.load(f)[guildID]
```

A loop is more suitable if the files have parallel structure and you'll be doing the same thing with all of them; separate code is more suitable if the files have different structure and you need to do different things with each of them.

Comment: @Łukasz-kwieciński's answer is better if you need the files open at the same time, for instance if you'll be merging or interleaving them or otherwise matching them up; however, for your usage, a one-by-one approach is simpler

Answer (score 2):

You can't open more than one file in a single `open` context manager, there are mainly two solutions:

1. Chain a couple of context managers

```py
with open("twit.json", "r") as f1, \
     open("insta.json", "r") as f2, \
     open("yt.json", "r") as f3:
    # do something with f1, f2 and f3
```

2. Use `contextlib.ExitStack`

```py
from contextlib import ExitStack

files = ["twit.json", "insta.json", "yt.json"]

with ExitStack() as stack:
    opened_files = [stack.enter_context(open(fp)) for fp in files]
    ...  # process `opened_files`
    # the files will be closed as soon as the context manager ends
```